3D printed wind turbine to power bank
I am 3d printing a wind turbine which will have wind going through it on and off and i wanted to know whats the best cheapests and smallest motor and controller i would need to get it to charge a small power bank. Maybe going output USB
So it would be
Turbine -> motor -> controller (need help on waterproof one) -> USB or charging lead like on the end of the solar stuff.
I want it to gradually charge the bank as and when its turning kind regards Rob the Noobie
